# how to make inner divs horizontally centered when pushed on top of each other on small screens

Tags: css, alignment, center

I have 4 divs (each counter) all next to each other when the screen is wide.y
When screen get smaller they stack on top of each other but they aligned to the right

I want them to be centered always, when the are 4 in line, two in two lines, and 1 in 4 lines.

how can I achieve this? the numbers might change and make the width of the divs variable

Take a look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Zivo/gp5wnL9f/1/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    --border: 1px solid #cccccc;

}

.numbers {
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #131128;
}

.odometer {
    display: inline-block;
    top: -7px;
}

.suffix {
    float: right
}

.frame {
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    height: 94px;
    overflow: hidden
}

.suffix p {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.odometer p {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.theme {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.hline {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: var(--border);
    /*    transform: translateY(-4px);*/
}

.num-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="numbers">
        <!--counter 1 - Sensors-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="10">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Sensors</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 2 - ICO-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="13">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
<!--
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
-->
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">IOC Types</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 3 - Scanners-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="550">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Scanners</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 4 - Attackers-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="5">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Attackers</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
            let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('odometer');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                let goal = elements[i].getAttribute("odometer-goal");
                elements[i].innerHTML = goal;
            }
        }, 1000);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from your class `.theme` and add the following `flex` properties to `.numbers`:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

- The first property will activate flex layout
- `flex-wrap: wrap` alows the row of elements to wrap if there is not enough space
- `justify-content: center` will make the elements centered instead of the default alignment (depending on text direction)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    --border: 1px solid #cccccc;

}

.numbers {
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #131128;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.odometer {
    display: inline-block;
    top: -7px;
}

.suffix {
    float: right
}

.frame {
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    height: 94px;
    overflow: hidden
}

.suffix p {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.odometer p {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.theme {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px;
}

.hline {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: var(--border);
    /*    transform: translateY(-4px);*/
}

.num-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="numbers">
        <!--counter 1 - Sensors-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="10">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Sensors</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 2 - ICO-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="13">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
<!--
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
-->
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">IOC Types</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 3 - Scanners-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="550">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Scanners</div>
        </div>
        <!--counter 4 - Attackers-->
        <div class="sensors theme">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="odometer" odometer-goal="5">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="suffix">
                    <p>k+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hline"></div>
            <div class="num-title">Attackers</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
            let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('odometer');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                let goal = elements[i].getAttribute("odometer-goal");
                elements[i].innerHTML = goal;
            }
        }, 1000);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get what you asked for, add `text-align: center;` to the `.numbers` class, and also remove `float: left;` from `.theme` class and add `display: inline-block;` to `.theme` also.

Here are the final classes:

```css
.numbers {
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #131128;
    text-align: center; /* new */
}

.theme {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px;
    /* float: left; */ /* removed */
    display: inline-block; /* new */
}
```